# How to show the following summation

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Show that $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+k}\right)=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}\log{2}-G$$ where $G=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$

I tried to write the summation in terms of logarithmic integral. Please give some  hints.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an active contest.

Comment: Feel free to flag for unlocking once the contest/deadline has passed.